# Showing an array in React-Admin

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-admin, dataprovider

I'm trying to create a phonebook app using react-admin. I created a dataProvider and  i want to display the `number` and `type` together, how should I do this? It does not show me any `number` or `type` in the output.

dataprovider.js

```
import fakeDataProvider from 'ra-data-fakerest';

const dataProvider = fakeDataProvider({
  contacts: [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "jack",
      numbers: [
        {number: '09367371111', typeId: 1},
        {number: '36059988', typeId: 2},
      ],
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "sara",
      numbers: [
        {number: '09365551111', typeId: 1},
      ],
    },
  ],
  typeCalls: [
    {id: 1, type: 'Mobile'},
    {id: 2, type: 'Home'},
    {id: 3, type: 'Work'},
    {id: 4, type: 'Other'},
  ],
});

export default dataProvider;
```

contacts.js

```
/// --- Show ---
export const ShowContact = (props) => {
  return (
    <Show {...props} actions={<ShowActionsOnTopToolbar/>} title={<ContactTitle/>}>
      <SimpleShowLayout>
        <TextField source="id"/>
        <TextField source="name"/>

        <ReferenceArrayField source="numbers" reference="contacts">
          <Datagrid>
            <TextField source="number"/>
            <TextField source="type"/>
          </Datagrid>
        </ReferenceArrayField>

      </SimpleShowLayout>
    </Show>
  )
};
```

Answer (score 1):

`ReferenceArrayField` is used to reference a table/set outside of the current record. Hence referencing the `contacts` while rendering the contacts themselves is not really sensible but also no referencing is needed as for the structure of your data.

The plain `ArrayField` should do the job as the record's `numbers` field is already an array with objects - just iterate them this way:

*Note you have a typo on the snippet above on `type` -> `typeId`. Sources should match API prop names strictily.

```
<ArrayField source="numbers">
  <Datagrid>
      <TextField source="number"/>
      <TextField source="typeId"/>
  </Datagrid>
</ArrayField>
```